# Radzen data grid LoadDataArgs not updating after set FilterValue manually

Tags: blazor, radzen

I'm trying to manually set `FilterValue` for a radzen datagrid column.

```
var column = DataGrid.ColumnsCollection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Property.Equals("MyProperty"));
column.FilterValue = "MyValue";

StateHasChanged();
DataGrid.Reload();
```

Then grid invoke `LoadDataAsync` method to reload data.

```
protected async Task LoadDataAsync(LoadDataArgs loadDataArgs)
{           
   //load data
}
```

but `loadDataArgs.Filter` is getting an empty string. Do I need to invoke/notify an event other than `DataGrid.Reload()` after manually changing `FilterValue` ?